# Combining two or more CSS selectors with a boolean condition

Tags: css, css-selectors

Is there a way to combine two or more CSS selectors using a boolean condition - `and`, `or`, `not`?

Consider this `<div>`:

```
<div class="message error">
    You have being logged out due too much activity.
</div>
```

Could I select only those elements that contain both the classes for instance?

Something along the lines of `div.message && div.error`?

Comment: Where do you want to do the selecting?  In Javascript (using a lib?) or in a stylesheet or other language?

Comment: these selectors will go in a stylesheet.

Comment: The question has already been answered correctly, but note that double class selectors don't work in our dear friend IE6.

Comment: i am working on a new application, so maybe i should figure out exactly how many of my users would be IE6 to decide if that's even worth supporting. it's a maintenance nightmare just to have IE6 support. the time spent fixing IE6 specific bugs could instead be used in adding awesome improvements to the application.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

These should work:

```
&& = div.message.error {}
|| = div.message, div.error {}
```

Don't think you can do "not"

Edit: Just did a quick test to confirm:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            div.error.message {
                background-color: red;
            }
            div.message, div.error {
                border: 1px solid green;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>None</div>
        <div class="error">Error</div>
        <div class="message">Message</div>
        <div class="error message">Error Message</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The "message", "error" and "error message" divs all have a green border and only the "error message" div has a red background.

Comment: perfect.. `not` is not a big worry, only `and` and `or` are.. wow we have a tongue twister here :) .. thanks a lot for the detailed example.

Comment: Great solution. Just curious, is the solution formally documented anywhere like in CSS spec, etc.? Useful to reference.

Answer (score 5):

Try `div.message.error`.

Comment: ... that, I believe is the "and" case. For "or" you can simply repeat the line with each class.

Answer (score 1):

This is a seriously old post, but I came across it and figured I'd add to it with the current CSS `:not()` selector:

**Select BOTH classes**

```
.message.error {}
```

**Select EITHER class**

```
.message, .error {}
```

**Select NEITHER class**

```
div:not(.message):not(.error) {}
```

```css
.message {
  border: 1px solid;
}

.error {
  color: red;
}

.message,
.error {
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  padding: 12px;
}

.message.error {
  background: #ffcfcf;
}

div:not(.message):not(.error) {
  font: normal 20px "Comic Sans MS", cursive, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div class="message">
    ONLY .message
</div>

<div class="error">
    ONLY .error
</div>

<div class="message error">
    BOTH classes
</div>

<div class="neither">
    NEITHER class
</div>
```