# Using css selector for containing more than 1 value in attributes

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

In css, IF i want to select (for example) 4 `div`s that the class of them Contains two types of value How should i select them ?

For example, I want to use :

```
div[class*="test"] OR [class*="myname2"] OR [class*="myname3"] [class*="myname4"]
```

What is the best Way to select them ALL ?

I want to select the div s that the class of them contains any of my names .

Comment: Why not just use `div.test` etc? though you wont avoid duplicate selectors, you will still get cleaner code.

Comment: because i want to Select Any one who contains my name !

Comment: Your question is difficult to understand. Do you mean you want to select any div that has one of the following class names: `test` `myname2` `myname3` `myname4`?

Comment: @user3509851 You are being a little rude to people who are trying to help you. Also, a logical `OR` in CSS is achieved with commas, as you've already been told. You could easily have found this by searching. For example, [Combining two or more CSS selectors with a boolean condition](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2144751/combining-two-or-more-css-selectors-with-a-boolean-condition)

Answer (score 2):

I might have miss-understood, but I think this is what you are looking for:

```
.test, .myname2, .myname3, .myname4 { // stuff }
```

Comment: You did, in a way. The `*=` attribute selector applies to any element that its attribute *contains* the value.

Comment: ok, sorry, but commas are still the way to go :)

Comment: @Boaz You are right, is there any way to select like the thing i need ?

Answer (score 1):

Use commas

```
div[class*="test"], div[class*="myname2"], div[class*="myname3"], div[class*="myname4"]
```

Comment: I don't want to select every and every one, I want to combine them all in one Selector !

Comment: That _is_ one selector. That's the only way you can really do it that I know of

Comment: This is not Going to work :| Because it is ONE selector , not selecting them all .

Comment: I don't understand what you want then. Try rewording your question