# Combining Protractor locators

Tags: javascript, protractor

What should I do if I want to find a repeater that also has a specific class? Or if I want to find a binding containing text?

What if I wanted to find an element by repeater *OR* CSS selector (matching elements that have a specific repeater expression OR, e.g. a specific class / attribute)?

This is a very general question. I'm not exactly interested in those specific cases, but in a general way to combine those locators.

Protractor allows locators to be chained (i.e.: `element(by.this(...)).element(by.that(...))`), but that will look for child elements instead. I want to do something similar, but filter elements using more than one locator, or find elements that match any of *n* locators.

Is this currently possible? Would such a feature be undesirable or hard to implement for some reason?

Filtering example:

```
// Template:
<li ng-repeat="fruit in fruits">...</li>

// Locator:
var evenFruitElements = element.all(by.repeater("fruit in fruits")).filter(by.css(":nth-child(even)"));
```

OR example:

```
// Template:
<span class="something-interesting">...</span>
<span class="something-else-similarly-interesting">...</span>

// Locator:
var interestingElements = element.all(by.css(".something-interesting"), by.css(".something-else-similarly-interesting"));
```

Answer (score 1):

1. There is an API for adding custom locators: http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ProtractorBy.prototype.addLocator

   ```
   // Add the custom locator.
   by.addLocator('buttonTextSimple',
   function(buttonText, opt_parentElement, opt_rootSelector) {
   // This function will be serialized as a string and will execute in the
   // browser. The first argument is the text for the button. The second
   // argument is the parent element, if any.
   var using = opt_parentElement,
       buttons = using.querySelectorAll('button');

   // Return an array of buttons with the text.
   return Array.prototype.filter.call(buttons, function(button) {
       return button.textContent === buttonText;
   });

   // Use the custom locator.
   element(by.buttonTextSimple('Go!')).click();
   ```
2. CSS selectors can do wonders sometimes:

   ```
   var interestingElements = element.all(by.css(".something-interesting"), by.css(".something-else-similarly-interesting"));
   ```

   can be actually implemented(as found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2144801):

   ```
   element.all(by.css(".something-interesting,.something-else-similarly-interesting"))
   ```

Comment: CSS selectors are great precisely because they are so composable, but they don't speak Angular bindings, for example. Writing a new locator for each locator combination I want is begging for maintenance problems...

Comment: sure. That's is why I mentioned both options: powerful one and simple one

Comment: While trying to combine as above I get an error:- TS2346 Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target